# Careers and newsletter ads over each other

Tags: bug, status-completed, firefox, rendering

In my Firefox 5.0 on Windows 7, ads for careers and the newsletter are sometimes shown one over the other, which looks really bad. Refreshing the page often helps, but the problem sometimes shows again.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @Jeff, I'm not completely sure, but it seems it only happens on certain questions, for example [the one in the screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886861/how-to-add-a-post-to-a-tab-in-my-blogger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed, thanks for the heads-up.